# is it possible to have a C/C++ GUI application in linux bare-bone server?

Tags: c++, c, linux, user-interface, ssh

I am very disappointed with my school linux server when doing the homework on it. 
The reason is: my homework requires to make GUI application.

All the tool that I have is: 
- ssh from  my local machine to school machine
- gcc/g++ in my school machine

I have been thinking and tried out different solutions for a week. 
I still can't be able to figure out how to bring GUI to my application.

Here is some solutions I tried:
- Install some graphical library (sdl,ncurses...) but school computer does not allow to install because i'm not the root user
- Try to compile with /X11/ to produce X-GUI application. Then running it throgh ssh (tunneling). This does not work either because school computer does not have headers file located in X11.

So, What CAN I DO? Anybody has suggestion? 
I will thank you million times if you could help for a solution.

Thanks you much. 
tsubasa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to install most things, like ncurses or even X11, in user space (in your home directory), if you install them from source. With a Gnu package, you just use --prefix= as an argument to configure, like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/name/of/directory/to/install/into
```

I'm not sure about the other packages.

Comment: I tried this but there's error:
apt-get install ncurses
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13 Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: @tsubasa: you cannot use apt-get since you are not root, you should download source package ie .tar.gz .tar.bz2

Comment: You will probably need to build ncurses from source to install into your home directory; most package managers require root for access to their metadata stores.

Comment: how can I build ncurses from source like you said? I have tried to use ./configure, it works ok. but when doing the 'make install', problem again with root privileges. So how can I be able to build ncurse from the source? Please help.

Comment: @tsubasa -- when you do ./configure, do ./configure --help  and you should have the ability to pass in a different install path (that will be used later for 'make install')

Comment: @tsubasa: use --prefix=/name/of/directory/to/install/into

Comment: In particular, `--prefix=$HOME` to install into your home directory.

Comment: I would never install into my home directory.

Comment: Kinopiko: Then you've never really used a real multiuser system.  Typically it's the *only* place you can write to, other than `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`.

Answer (score 2):

Without a GUI library to link against, you won't be able to develop a C/C++ app on that server.  It seems to me that you have a few options:

1)  Develop this GUI app someplace else.  If it has to be in Linux, and you're a Windows/Mac user, you can install Ubuntu (or some other Linux Distro) on a Virtual Machine and get a full featured environment.

2)  Contact the Linux administrator to explain the homework assignment and convince them to install a GUI package for you. (It may help to have your professor also contact the Linux Administrator)  (If you don't know who the linux admin is, try emailing root@linuxbox

3)  Bend the rules on what a "GUI" environment is.  For example, can your C/C++ app output HTML files for a GUI-like experience through a web-browser?

4)  Try to install some sort of GUI package inside your account on the server.  This will likely fail unless you are very, very good at administering a linux box, and you've hand-built packages before.

Answer (score 1):

Could do it with [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could ditch the school server and use [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to run a linux VM locally on your machine and develop on that.  It's free.

Answer (score 0):

From "INSTALL" file in ncurses source archive:

> ```
> The package gets installed beneath the --prefix directory as follows:
>
> In $(prefix)/bin:          tic, infocmp, captoinfo, tset,
>           reset, clear, tput, toe
> In $(prefix)/lib:          libncurses*.* libcurses.a
> In $(prefix)/share/terminfo: compiled terminal descriptions
> In $(prefix)/include:      C header files
> Under $(prefix)/man:       the manual pages
>
> Note that the configure script attempts to locate previous
> ```
>
> installation of
>       ncurses, and will set the default prefix according to where it finds the
>       ncurses headers.
>
> ```
> Do not use commands such as
>
>   make install prefix=XXX
>
> to change the prefix after configuration, since the prefix value
> ```
>
> is used
>       for some absolute pathnames such as TERMINFO.  Instead do this
>
> ```
>   make install DESTDIR=XXX
> ```

So I'd recommend using "make install DESTDIR=XXX" where XXX is the location where you have write persmissions.

HTH